# Magento error in ProductController.php on line 578 and Apache Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: events, magento, logging

I am busy writing some observers for Magento and ran into an issue with all sorts of all strange error messages to which I could not easily find a solution.

Symptoms are:

- When saving a store view in Magento admin pages Apache would crash with a Segmentation fault (11) in the /var/log/apache2/error.log
- When saving products in Magento admin pages I would see empty pages or (with error logging on) I would see "Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() in ProductController.php on line 578" and the changes would not be saved

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not find an answer it took some time to find the solution. In my search for the correct event in Magento I had enabled logging of all Magento events to a separate log file from Mage.php.

After one day in a demo environment this file turned out to be around 13Mb big. Disabling the logging functions of all events sorted the two problems above. It still seems a bit strange to me as other functions did still work and I was able to save other admin pages.

Answer (score 0):

You may check magento log `tail -15 var/log/system.log`

```
ERR (3): Warning: include(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.  in /data/www/dev-store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

The problem was with exhausted space in /tmp folder. You may list files with size with

```
cd /tmp
ls -lha
```

remove large files by `sudo rm filename`